# apache with virtual hosts: 403 forbidden

Tags: macos, apache, unix

I know, this problem has been faced several times, but after reading many posts, it still does not work. the funny part: yesterday it worked. so, who can help me find the error? step by step:

I am using Apache/2.2.29 on Mac OS 10.8.5

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1       scripts
127.0.0.1       page
```

**/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**

```
[...]
ServerRoot "/usr"

User _www
Group _www

DocumentRoot "/Users/me/server"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
[...]
<Directory "/Users/me/server">
    MultiViews
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
[...]
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
[...]
```

**/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot "/Users/me/server/scripts"
        ServerName scripts
        ErrorLog "/Users/me/server/scripts/errlog"
        CustomLog "/Users/me/server/scripts/customlog" common

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

        DocumentRoot "/Users/me/server/page"
        ServerName scripts
        ErrorLog "/Users/me/server/page/log/errlog"
        CustomLog "/Users/me/server/page/log/customlog" common

</VirtualHost>
```

**Given Rights:** (Full rights for testing)

```
/Users/me/server
    drwxrwxrwx  5 _www     _www  

/Users/me/server/page 
    drwxrwxrwx  4 _www  _www
```

**Restart apache**

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

I tried to restart the browser as well

**Log Files**
All log files are empty

**Result**

```
http://localhost
http://page
```

neither of them works, I keep on getting the forbidden message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `ServerName` from `scripts` to `page` in second section in httpd-vhosts.conf.

Comment: but I better delete this post, because i think it's not for common interest.

Comment: @AntonHarald You can delete this if you want to but i think that you are providing pretty detailed configuration here which might help some newbie. Also it is not hurting anyone. This is what my opinion is.